# How to *named* @keyframes in SASS?

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, live-sass-compiler

I'm trying to create the following set of named @keyframes using a loop in SASS

```
@keyframes loading-1 {
    14.28% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}

@keyframes loading-2 {
    28.57% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}

@keyframes loading-3 {
    42.86% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}

@keyframes loading-4 {
    57.14% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}

@keyframes loading-5 {
    71.43% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}

@keyframes loading-6 {
    85.71% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}

@keyframes loading-7 {
    100% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
```

I've been looking at several references including StackOverflow, and none have address the type of @keyframe naming I'm trying to accomplish, and I really don't think there's any duplicate post that solves exactly this issue.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
$number-of-steps: 7;

@function to-fixed($float, $digits: 2) {
    $sass-precision: 5;
    
    @if $digits > $sass-precision {
      @warn "Sass sets default precision to #{$sass-precision} digits, and there is no way to change that for now."
      + "The returned number will have #{$sass-precision} digits, even if you asked for `#{$digits}`."
      + "See https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1122 for further informations.";
    }
    
    $pow: pow(10, $digits);
    @return round($float * $pow) / $pow;
}

   :


@for $l from 1 through $number-of-steps {

    @keyframes loading_#{$l} {
        {to-fixed((100/$l), 2)}% {
            opacity: 0.3;
        }
    }

}
```

But SASS complains with

```
Compilation Error
Error: expected "}".
   ╷
18 │     @keyframes loading-#{$l} {
                                   ^
```

Is there a way to dynamically create the name for these keyframes?

I'm using the "Live SASS Compiler" in Visual Code Studio, and it appears to be up-to-date.

TIA!

Comment: You are missing the `#` before the `to-fixed`. Also the logic is inverted so you get the `loading-1` to have 100% opacity and the `loading-7` to have 14.29%. See (*updated*) working [demo](https://shorturl.at/FJ027)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is no the dynamic names, you have two syntax errors. First is the missing `#` on your [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation/) of `to-fixed`:

```
#{to-fixed((100/$l), 2)}% {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

And second is your use of [`pow()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math/#pow), this function is not available as is, you have to import it from `sass:math`:

```
@use "sass:math";
$pow: math.pow(10, 2);
```

Note that `pow()` is only compatible with **Dart Dass** since v1.25.0.